# Genomic and sum of geometric random variables

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, biology, mathematical-biology

In their paper [The Maximum of independent Geometric Random Variables as the Time for Genomic Evolution](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263270731_The_Maximum_of_Independent_Geometric_Random_Variables_as_the_Time_for_Genomic_Evolution)the authors noted that if to consider the genomic word of L letters, than the measure of the time it takes to obtain a successful genomic word $R_L=max{X_1, \ldots, X_L}$. Where $X_i, i=1, \ldots, L$ are independent geometric random variables.

My questions is, what, in terms of genomic would mean an estimate of $E(\sum_{i=1}^La_iX_i)^{2n}$, where $a_i\in R$ are weights?